# What am I missing for authenticating a user with Devise and JWT in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, jwt

I followed this tutorial to set up authentication with JWT and devise https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-using-jwt-in-rails/. My authentication_controller looks like this:

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
  def authenticate_user
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email])
    if user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render json: payload(user) 
    else
      render json: {errors: ['Invalid Username/Password']}, status: 
:unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def payload(user)
    return nil unless user && user.id
    {
      auth_token: JsonWebToken.encode({user_id: user.id}),
      user: {id: user.id, email: user.email}
    }
  end
end
```

It maps to a route called auth_user, as shown here in my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :reviews

  resources :people do 
    resources :reviews 
  end 

  post 'auth_user' => 'authentication#authenticate_user'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {sessions: 'sessions', registrations: 
'registrations'}
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

All my other routes work, including posting to the devise routes, but this one give a 500 internal server error. Any ideas of what could be causing this behavior are greatly appreciated! For what its worth, I'm on Rails 5.1.5, JWT 2.1.0, and Devise 4.4.3. Thanks!

I checked the heroku logs after trying to send a request. They look like this:

```
2018-04-26T20:53:32.801349+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-26T20:53:32.801222 #4]  INFO -- : [bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224] Started POST "/auth_user" for 199.116.73.196 at 2018-04-26 20:53:32 +0000
2018-04-26T20:53:32.824053+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-26T20:53:32.823923 #4]  INFO -- : [bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224] Processing by AuthenticationController#authenticate_user as */*
2018-04-26T20:53:32.824188+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-26T20:53:32.824119 #4]  INFO -- : [bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224]   Parameters: {"email"=>"\"mike@mike.com\"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
2018-04-26T20:53:32.953483+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-04-26T20:53:32.953329 #4] DEBUG -- : [bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224]   [1m[36mUser Load (8.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "\"mike@mike.com\""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-04-26T20:53:32.963709+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-26T20:53:32.963569 #4]  INFO -- : [bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 139ms (ActiveRecord: 53.2ms)
2018-04-26T20:53:32.964567+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-26T20:53:32.964492 #4] FATAL -- : [bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224]   
2018-04-26T20:53:32.964715+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-26T20:53:32.964649 #4] FATAL -- : [bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224] NoMethodError (undefined method `valid_password?' for nil:NilClass):
2018-04-26T20:53:32.964805+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-26T20:53:32.964742 #4] FATAL -- : [bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224]   
2018-04-26T20:53:32.964904+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-26T20:53:32.964844 #4] FATAL -- : [bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224] app/controllers/authentication_controller.rb:4:in `authenticate_user'
2018-04-26T20:53:32.966716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/auth_user" host=rateyouracquaintanceapi.herokuapp.com request_id=bb58b729-4d79-4940-b73d-2bc433c8d224 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=172ms status=500 bytes=203 protocol=https
```

Still a bit baffled as to what's breaking, but at least it's clear now where the problem is!

Change the code in authenticate_user to this:

```
def authenticate_user
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email])
    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render json: payload(user) 
    else
      render json: {errors: ['Invalid Username/Password']}, status: 
:unauthorized
    end
  end
```

Now I get the expected json response for if the user was not found, but if I input the data for a valid user it does not give the proper response. Could this be a problem with the find_for_database_authentication method? The logs now show this:

```
2018-04-26T21:24:07.327940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST 
path="/auth_user" host=rateyouracquaintanceapi.herokuapp.com 
request_id=95dcfdd7-55d5-4a24-b8e4-d597737c4b02 fwd="199.116.73.196" 
dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=401 bytes=286 protocol=https
2018-04-26T21:24:07.319101+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-26T21:24:07.318981 
#4]  INFO -- : [95dcfdd7-55d5-4a24-b8e4-d597737c4b02] Started POST 
"/auth_user" for 199.116.73.196 at 2018-04-26 21:24:07 +0000
2018-04-26T21:24:07.320412+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-26T21:24:07.320296 
#4]  INFO -- : [95dcfdd7-55d5-4a24-b8e4-d597737c4b02] Processing by 
AuthenticationController#authenticate_user as */*
2018-04-26T21:24:07.320476+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-26T21:24:07.320410 
#4]  INFO -- : [95dcfdd7-55d5-4a24-b8e4-d597737c4b02]   Parameters: 
{"email"=>"\"mike@mike.com\"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
2018-04-26T21:24:07.329226+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-04-26T21:24:07.328689 
#4] DEBUG -- : [95dcfdd7-55d5-4a24-b8e4-d597737c4b02]   [1m[36mUser Load 
(5.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" 
= 
$1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "\"mike@mike.com\""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-04-26T21:24:07.330108+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-26T21:24:07.330005 
#4]  INFO -- : [95dcfdd7-55d5-4a24-b8e4-d597737c4b02] 
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash 
(0.17ms)
2018-04-26T21:24:07.330482+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-26T21:24:07.330370 
#4]  INFO -- : [95dcfdd7-55d5-4a24-b8e4-d597737c4b02] Completed 401 
Unauthorized in 10ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)
```

Comment: Hey, a 500 error is non-descriptive. Try monitoring the running rails server's output for when you get the error, and post it here. It'll help us diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your logs, I see:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `valid_password?' for nil:NilClass):
```

This probably coming from the line:

```
user.valid_password?(params[:password])
```

Which means your `user` variable is `nil`. This is happening because `user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email])` is returning `nil`.

Check to see if your user exists in the database by running the rails console, using `heroku run rails c`. If not, create it, and your code should work fine.

Comment: Right. But the user I am passing in exists, so it should be found. Also, if the user didn't exist, this should be handled by the else condition. Not sure why that's not working properly.

Comment: Actually, the the `if` condition only checks for `user.valid_password?`, if you want it to check for whether a user is found, you should change it to `if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])`

Comment: Okay I see that now. I changed the code to check if a user was found, but it didn't find one even though a user with those credentials exists.

Comment: Not entirely sure why the tutorial you're using uses `find_for_database_authentication`, but try changing that line to  `user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])`, this question seems to have similar code and the questioner says that changing it fixed it for them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980041/find-for-database-authentication-vs-find-by-in-rails-devise-app

Comment: I made that change but it didn't fix the issue. I wonder if it could have to do with fact that the password is being passed in as filtered?

Comment: The password isn't being passed in as filtered, but it's being filtered in the rails server logs. Try this: access the rails console on heroku with `heroku run rails console`, and see what gets returned when you run `User.find_by email: 'EMAIL_HERE'`

Comment: The user is found in the rails console

Comment: If I remove the validation for the password and just validate that a user was found it still doesnt work. The line in the logs that says "Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash" is interesting. I have serializers set up for my other models, but not my user model. Should I?

Comment: WOW okay I'm stupid I was including quotes around the data but apparently postman doesnt like that. It works now. Thanks!